# Stranded on an asteroid after pirate attack, asteroid has an abandoned monastery a novel

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the name of a science fiction novel that starts with a male teenager stranded on an asteroid after getting ejected in a life pod by his family after the family freighter is attacked by pirates. The asteroid has a ruin of a monastery where the past inhabitants attempted to contact aliens by sending signals into deep space and got attacked for this.  The asteroid is covered in a material that gathers useful resources like water. The blurb of the book also mentions his only companion is the still-alive head of a philosopher.

I read it sometime after 2012 and been unable to find its name.

Comment: Maybe [Forbidden the Stars](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8698253-forbidden-the-stars) by Valmore Daniels? It does start with the boy, _Alex Manez_, stranded on an asteroid after a pirate attack that kills his parents, and there is a weird element on the asteroid. But I don't think there's any ruined monastery or philosopher's head, and the weird element enables faster than light travel rather than gathering water.

Comment: Hello John, I just checked Forbidden the Stars by Valmore Daniels. I read the first pages and the description about the accident that killed his parents and it is not the right story. Looks like an interesting story.

Comment: Oh, well, I'll keep searching! :-)